# Troubles With Two On Click Listeners In One Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

need some help with creating my main menu.  I have successfully made one on click listener that switches to a different activity but im having troubles getting the second one to work.  The application runs fine in the simulation but when i go to click the weight gin button nothing happens.  I just cant seem to find the problem

```
      package com.example.bmiworking;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn,btn1,btn2,btn3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBMI);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGain);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonBMI) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
        public void onClick1(View d) {
            if (d.getId() == R.id.buttonGain) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, weightgain.class));
            }
        }
    }


package com.example.bmiworking;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class weightgain extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weightgain);
}
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" 
    android:background="@drawable/grunge">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Menu"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BMI Goal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         android:id="@+id/bSub"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBMI"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="BMI Calculator"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Muscle Loss Workouts" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         android:id="@+id/bSub"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGain"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Muscle Gain Workouts"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bmiworking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bmiworking.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
            <activity
            android:name="com.example.bmiworking.weightgain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
    </application>
```

Edit with stack trace:

```
  01-24 02:34:34.739: D/dalvikvm(808): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
    01-24 02:34:34.754: D/AndroidRuntime(808): Shutting down VM
    01-24 02:34:34.754: W/dalvikvm(808): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bmiworking/com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    01-24 02:34:34.819: E/AndroidRuntime(808):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it so it is like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonBMI) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
  }
  if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonGain) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, weightgain.class));
  }
}
```

You only really override `onClick(View v)` and so, both button presses make `onClick(View v)` called (`onClick1()` never gets used). Then since you have an if, the second button doesn't get to start anything. Of course, if you have a lot of buttons, consider using a `switch` statement (like ρяσѕρєяK outlined). However, the idea is the same, you only use 1 method.

Comment: i would also have to add d to the parameters aswell then?

Comment: @user2005486 no, checking the ids is fine. `v` changes based on which button is called. It may be `btn` or `btn1`, the id check takes care of determining which is which.

Comment: It looks to me like the 'd' in d.getId() is a typo. Both 'if' statements should be if(v.getId() ....

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek you're right. Fixed with `v` since that's what we're passing off. This is why `switches` are nicer :-)

Comment: threw this 01-24 02:30:12.982: E/AndroidRuntime(765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 02:30:12.982: E/AndroidRuntime(765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bmiworking/com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu

Comment: @user2005486 post the whole stack trace as an **edit** to your question.

Comment: @user2005486 you can edit your question as many times as needed. Your question is the thing at the top, that you also posted code in. Or at the very least use http://pastebin.com/, mega won't work for me.

Comment: just added to the question my bad.

Comment: @suggamuggafugga try cleaning your project and if that doesn't fix anything, post your **updated** code. Also, how are you starting this Activity?

Comment: @suggamuggafugga so is your issue with this question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

change onClick code as using switch case instead of if-else :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 switch(v.getId()){
  case R.id.buttonBMI: 
          startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
       break;

  case R.id.buttonGain:  
       startActivity(new Intent(this, weightgain.class));
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: threw this error 01-24 02:27:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 02:27:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bmiworking/com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.bmiworking.MainMenu

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something like the correct implement about the Intent and the OnClick method. Please try this on replacinging your code into mine and you will get a good result;

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(btn)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (v.equals(btn1)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, weightgain.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

In above, "**btn**" and "**btn1**" are your buttons.

Please let me know your result.

Answer (score 0):

First Change onClick code as,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 switch(v.getId()){
 case R.id.buttonBMI: 
      startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class));
   break;

 case R.id.buttonGain:  
   startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, weightgain.class));
   break;
}
}
```

Dont pass **this** when creating new instance, pass it as **ActivityName.this**

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonBMI: 
         startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class));
         break;

    case R.id.buttonGain:  
        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, weightgain.class));
        break;
    }
}
```

Or

Try This 2nd Approach

```
public void buttonBMIClick(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class));
}

public void buttonGainClick(View view){
     startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, weightgain.class));
}
```

and make you layout XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBMI"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="BMI Calculator"
    android:onClick="buttonBMIClick"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGain"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Muscle Gain Workouts"
    android:onClick="buttonGainClick"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```